# How I could loop over an array of objects and add a property from each object to a variable using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array that contains the several instances of the following struct

```
public struct IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION
{
    public uint VirtualAddress;
    public uint SizeOfBlock;
}
```

I want to add the value of `SizeOfBlock` to a variable for every struct in the array

Currently, I am doing this like this

```
var count = 0;

foreach(var structure in theArray)
{
    count += (int) structure.SizeOfBlock;
}
```

I was wondering how I could use linq to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it by this way.

```
var count = theArray.Sum(x=>x.SizeOfBlock);
```